# Is it possible to assign a different error message to the same validation attribute in different context?

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say I have two types of entities (`A` and `B`) having the same attribute `ends_at`.

In my lang files, I want to have two messages for ends_at, depending whether it refers to A or B.

I tried:

```
'custom_rule' => 'Default message',

'custom' => array(
    'A.ends_at' => [ 'custom_rule' => 'Message for A'  ],
    'B.ends_at' => [ 'custom_rule' => 'Message for B'  ]
),
```

but it does not work; it displays default message instead.

Do you know how to display only the corresponding message without changing the attribute?

Comment: You'd need to have custom-rule-A and custom-rule-B. Make custom-rule-B just return custom-rule-A as a function, but meanwhile you can then specify a unique message for A and B in your lang file

Answer (score 0):

Best way forward when you're doing validation is to create a validation service then you can define the default lang messages for your rules and also get specific with messages for instances of those rules. Here's a basic example of a login form validation:

```
class Login extends Validator {

    public static $rules = [

        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|numeric',

    ];

    public static $messages = [

        'email.required'    => 'Please enter an email address.',
        'email.email'       => 'Please enter a valid email address.',
        'password.required' => 'Please enter a password.',

    ];
}
```

Check out the great video tutorial from Jeffrey Way here: https://tutsplus.com/lesson/validation-services/

It takes you through creating the service in about 10mins (skip past the basic validation info to about 10mins in to get started straight away on the validation service).

Comment: What if I have a multi-language site? Will I be able to read these $messages through a language file?

Comment: The great thing about the validation service is you can extend it with as many different instances of language as you like. So you might want a `Login_EN` (english) class or a `Login_ES` (spanish) class, you can choose which of these to use in your controller logic. The tutorial I've added will take you through how to use the service.